# laravel echo pusher broadcasting on different server

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

if we have a project based on **Two servers** one for the `front end (React / Vuejs)` and one for the `backend (laravel application)`.

The front-end only talks with the server using api service. Now i know how to broadcast a message or notification on the same server using pusher , and laravel-echo.

But what if we have this kind of scenario. I have my mind blank on this what to do. Even i dont know that can we **broadcast** something accross different domains

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at websockets.
You can create a websocket and have your frontend app subscribe to it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API